# Dynamic Drop Down on iPhone

Tags: javascript, iphone, mobile, dynamic, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to replicate the following Fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/3UWk2/1/) on mobile (more specifically iPhone Safari) but it seems like it is not running the javascript correctly, any suggestions? Thanks!!

Here's the js:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#00Ni0000007XPVF').bind('change', function() {
        var elements = $('div.container_drop').children().hide(); // hide all the elements
        var value = $(this).val();

        if (value.length) { // if somethings' selected
            elements.filter('.' + value).show(); // show the ones we want
        }
    }).trigger('change');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be using the cached value. `hide` does not return anything. So fails when you try to show them again.

```
var elements = $('div.container_drop').children().hide();
```

Supposed to be

```
var elements = $('div.container_drop').children();
    elements.hide();
```

**Code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#00Ni0000007XPVF').bind('change', function() {
        // cache the value
        var elements = $('div.container_drop').children(); 
            elements.hide();   // hide all the elements
        var value = $(this).val();

        if (value.length) { // if somethings' selected
            elements.filter('.' + value).show(); // show the ones we want
        }
    }).trigger('change');
});
```

Comment: Is this solution specifically for mobile? I'm asking because I have it implemented on web and it works as is across all browsers.